# Is it possible to #linkTo a route with 2 dynamic segments using 'this'?

Tags: ember.js

I implemented a variant of the [solution for having a route with multiple dynamic segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703792/multiple-dynamic-segments-in-ember-js) where one of the models is an array.

The implementation can be found [**here**](http://jsbin.com/idowif/11/edit).

Basically, the router is defined like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("ab", { path: "/:a/:b" });
});
```

When you navigate to this route, `a` is used as is, and `b` is transformed into an array. Both 'models' are passed to their respective controllers which both render a template into a named outlet of the application template.

Now, I would like to use the `#linkTo` helper in the template which displays the array. To make this work, I would somehow need to combine `{{this}}` and the current value of `a` into a single object.

Then, the idea is to be able to do something like this for that template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="b">
  Template b:
    {{#each model}}
      {{#linkTo ab {a: {{this}}, b: controller.content} }} {{this}} {{/linkTo}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Is that even possible, or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple arguments to `linkTo`. This also works with nested routes. Ember walks the tree of nested routes and sets the models for it accordingly.

```
{{#linkTo 'ab' a b}}Foo{{/linkTo}}
```

Where `a` and `b` are models that are be resolvable within that template.

### Edit: Post comment

What you need is a custom `serialize` method that converts the model into an object with keys corresponding to the ids defined on the route. The `serialize` method is used by `linkTo` to build the route.

```
serialize: function(model) {
  return { a: model.get('a'), b: model.get('b') }; 
}
```

Note, On the `model` hook for resource's route you will need to use the same keys from the params hash to do a lookup. This is for use when the user directly visits the url instead of via `linkTo`.

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udogar/2/edit) example.

Comment: I've tried this, and unless I'm completely off track, it doesn't work because in the example above, I do not have any nested routes, but instead a single route with 2 dynamic segments. When the #linkTo helper walks the tree, it sees a single route and takes only the first object, then throws an error saying: "More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: ab"

Comment: You are correct, this pattern doesn't work for non-nested routes. Thanks for posting it, It helped me clarify a few things. I've updated my answer that correctly addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do exactly what I wanted by adding a computed property to the `BController`. You can see the result [here](http://jsbin.com/idowif/13/edit). Basically, if you click on a link from template b, the 'detail' will be displayed in template a, but you can play with the :b segment of the URL and model `a` will remain untouched.